# Terraform : Specifying the working directory when running terraform apply/plan

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Is there any way (or workaround) to specify the working directory when running terraform apply or terraform plan ?
For example :

```
terraform apply working_dir/vpc
terraform apply working_dir/dns
terraform apply working_dir/postgres
terraform apply working_dir/service-a
terraform apply working_dir/service-b
```

I know there's a target option where we can specify the resources to **target**. But here I need a folder to have more abstraction.
The final goal is to be able to setup the infrastructure running the following commands :

```
make vpc
make dns
make postgres
make service-a
make service-b
```

Comment: you can use `pushd $working_dir` and `popd`

Comment: pushd and popd will not be very useful in my use cases. 
Even `cd` would be better.

Comment: so why not just go with this, more than ask for a new feature in terraform. If you do think that's useful feature, terraform is open source and it welcomes you to contribute the codes to add this feature in it.

Comment: Why don't you utilise a make file that does the functionality you desire?

Answer (score 28):

These days you can also use global option [-chdir](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/index.html):

> The chdir option instructs Terraform to **change its working directory** to the given directory before running the given subcommand. This means that any files that Terraform would normally read or write in the current working directory will be read or written in the given directory instead.

For example:

```
terraform -chdir=environments/production apply
```

Answer (score 5):

You can specify a plan or directory when issuing the [`apply`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/apply.html) command.  Your examples are valid apply commands.

> Usage: terraform apply [options] [dir-or-plan]

Answer (score 0):

Execute below commands from parent directory having multiple directories containing terraform (*.tf) files.

To execute terraform:

```
terraform init dir-name
terraform validate dir-name
terraform plan -detailed-exitcode -out=plan-name.out dir-name
terraform apply plan-name.out
```

To destroy use:

```
terraform destroy dir-name
```

Comment: use -chdir option

Comment: @ThomasDecaux why? This looks a bit cleaner. Is there a specific reason to use one over another?